# How to symmetrically adjust data by removing certain value

Tags: dataset, weighted-mean, weighted-sampling, group-differences

Say I have a data set in the following format: 
{a:200, b: 100; c:400}

The sum of a, b and c equals 700. Now, I have another value which is supposed to be the actual total say 500.

How do I adjust this difference of 200 in the initial data set (the values for a, b and c must be proportionately decreased summing 200 - something like a weighted difference)?

Comment: This question does not have a unique answer: the answer depends on how the data were obtained.  From that one can develop a probability model, allowing for (say) the prediction of the true values represented by a, b, and c, *conditional* on knowing their sum equals 500.  Perhaps, then, to make this question answerable, you could fill us in on how these values were obtained and what the purpose of adjusting them is?